# Tkinter I can only see the background

Tags: python, tkinter

I can only see the background and the button is visible if I stretch the window vertically.
How can I put the button onto the image?
The image is 1366*768

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, PhotoImage

root=Tk()
photo=PhotoImage(file="folder//file.gif")
w=Label(root, image=photo).pack()

btn=Button(root, text="press me").pack()

root.geometry("1366x768")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `.pack()` will not overlap widgets.  You'd either need to use `.place()` to manually give the two widgets overlapping coordinates, or `.grid()` with the same row/column numbers for both widgets.

Comment: Packing an object returns None. So if you want to edit the label later, better use `w = Label(root, image=photo')` and then type `w.pack()`. Else `w` will be a "NoneType".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a canvas instead of label if you want to place the button on an image.

```
canvas =tk.Canvas(root,width=1366,height=768)
canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor="nw",image=photo)

canvas.create_window(50,50,anchor="center",window=tk.Button(canvas,text="press me"))

canvas.pack()
```